# как отправить цели в метрику по загрузке оффлайн конверсий

Tags: yandex-metrika-api, яндекс-метрика

есть код

```
<?php 
$token = '';
$counterId = '';
$postfile = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------7zDUQOAIAE9hEWoV
Context-Length: 253
--------------------------7zDUQOAIAE9hEWoV
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="data.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

ClientId,Target,DateTime,Price
uf977bqvodfc694lsdmtftckij,45345345,'.time().',2
--------------------------7zDUQOAIAE9hEWoV--';
$url = 'https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/management/v1/counter/'. $counterId . '/offline_conversions/upload?client_id_type=USER_ID';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
    'Authorization: OAuth ' . $token
]);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['file' => $postfile]);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($curl_response);
>?
```

но в ответе пишется  -
{"errors":[{"error_type":"invalid_uploading","message":"Не найден параметр запроса.","location":"file"}],"code":400,"message":"Не найден параметр запроса."}bool(true) 
может кто то сталкивался и посоветует как решить, заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно включить в CURL

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);// Для отладки
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . "/headers.txt", "w+"));
// Для отладки (в файле можно увидеть что отправляется и что возвращается)
//Ну и дописываем ответ
 if($curl_response === false)
    {
        echo 'Ошибка curl: ' . curl_error($curl);
    }
     else  //ДЛЯ ТЕСТА
     {
         $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
         echo "curl_getinfo: \n";
        print_r($info);
     }
    // Закрываем дескриптор
    curl_close($curl);
```